# Can Rust and CyberDWARF be used together?

Tags: debugging, rust, emscripten, webassembly

Emscripten provides CyberDWARF for inspecting variables at runtime via the console as a JS API. Is it possible to use CyberDWARF when compiling Rust to asm.js or Wasm?

Source maps are possible, but it would be nice to be able to inspect variables that appear in the original source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not CyberDWARF, but you can use LLDB with Wasmtime: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/09/debugging-webassembly-outside-of-the-browser/

Comment: Rather nice. Just need to be able to debug it running within an app. Remote debugging support maybe.

Comment: Actually JIT debug support from lldb/gdb should allow it to be debugged within its parent app.